# Using models field as a dictionary key, but it's reading it as the default value?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, default

I have a dictionary defined as

```
BREED_CLASS = {
    'bdcl': ['Border Collie', BreedBdcl, 'BreedBdcl'],
}
```

and a model defined as

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    breed_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='')
```

I'm trying to use the breed_code as a key to access the items in the dictionary, for example like this

```
return BREED_CLASS[instance.breed_code][0]
```

but that raises a KeyError, with exception value '' aka the default value.

I've tried doing something like

```
bc = instance.breed_code
```

and that correctly returns the value saved to that instantiated object ('bdcl'). But when I put that into the dictionary access as so

```
    return BREED_CLASS[bc][0]
```

it gets me the same exact KeyError with the same exact exception value. How do I figure this out?

Comment: Python dictionaries uses hashes of your objects. Make sure `hash(instance.breed_code)` is the same value as `hash(bc)`. There might be some magic there giving you an object in one line but the string in another.

Comment: Okay those two hash's are not the same value. 
How would I go about using the breed_code to work as a key to access the dictionary then?

I thought    return BREED_CLASS[instance.breed_code][0] would work but it doesn't.

Comment: How do you instantiate instance?

Comment: From the template

     ``<select name="breed_code" required="required">
         {% for key, value in breed_types %}
      <option value={{key}}>{{value.0}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
  </select> ``

and then

``breed_code = request.POST.get('breed_code', '')``
``new_dog = BREED_CLASS[breed_code][1](breed_code=breed_code)``

Comment: Can you try quoting {{key]} ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be where the problem lies because the same error occurs even if I create a new instance via the django admin interface (Add dog +)

Comment: You never know. Also can you tell the output of `type(bc)`

Comment: With `bc = instance.breed_code`, `type(bc)` returns `<class 'str'>`

Comment: And I tried doing "{{key}}" and that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

The CharField class seems to be using the `__str__` magic method to return a string when you print it, giving you the illusion it is a string but it's actually an object. Your dictionary uses the actual string for storing the value but when you use `BREED_CLASS[instance.breed_code]` you are passing it the object. Converting your object to a string should fix it. Try this:

```
BREED_CLASS[str(instance.breed_code)][0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work either. Getting the same errors :/

Comment: bdcl. And that's why it's tearing me up. Because it seems like using that as a key would work, but it doesn't and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a workaround that gets me what I want, but I have no idea why it works.

This by itself does not work

```
return BREED_CLASS[instance.breed_code][2]
```

But having this for loop that iterates through the keys does

```
for key in BREED_CLASS:
    if key == instance.breed_code:
        return  BREED_CLASS[instance.breed_code][2]
```

Notice that both return calls are identical, with instance.breed_code being used for the dict key index.
Does anyone have an answer as for why this is?